# Duda de sintaxis en mi javascript

Tags: php, jquery

espero anden bien. Tengo un código funcional en el que al clikear en este div

```
<div ><?php echo "<a href=javascript:hola('$imagen');>
            <img src='$imagen' width='100' height='100' />
                  </a>";
       ?></div>
```

se aplica una función, la cual es esta

```
function hola(imagen) {
   var confirma = window.confirm("Si");
   if (confirma) {

       window.location = 'productos.php?img='+imagen
   }
}
```

Luego tengo una página que recibe el "img" que es igual a `+imagen`

```
  if (isset($_GET["img"])) {
  $q=$_GET["img"];
  echo "$q<br>"; }
```

Mi idea es mandar el valor de `imagen` pero sin tener que refrescar la página, la única idea que se ocurrió es la que les estoy mostrando, pero solo sé mandarlo refrescando la página y eso no me sirve.No sé otra forma de escribirlo y ahí es cuando les pido su ayuda que ustedes son más experimentados que yo.

Comment: Probablemente esto te sirva: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300069/error-previsualizar-imagen-en-modal

Comment: La mejor forma de hacerlo es con Ajax, [como estabas intentando aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/339768/29967). ¿Por qué no seguiste por esa vía?